# Date range picker with twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap and can't find any date pickers that work with my needs or html.

I've got a form and within that some select tags. I want to know how you can insert a date picker for twitter bootstrap that will then send the relevant picked dates by the user once they have submitted the request. This is my html so far:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span11">
<form id ="eventForm">         
     <select name="event" id="abc">
        <option value="w" selected="selected">US</option>
        <option value="e">uk</option>
        <option value="r">prk</option>
        <option value="t">chn</option>  
     </select>

     <select name="period" id="time">
        <option value="beginning" selected="selected">from start</option>
        <option value="the last 24 hours">Last 24 hours</option>
        <option value="the previous week">Previous week</option>  
     </select>

    <input type="submit" id="open" onclick="heading()" value="Start" />
    <input type="button" onclick="closeMap()" value="Stop Request"/>
</form>
</div>

 <div class="span1">
   <form name="moreAnalysis" id="moreAnalysis" action="/p" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Further Analysis">
   </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

So ideally where I'm letting user choose periods I would want them to choose from a date menu.

I've tried several options and none seem to work and this has taken be all day as a html/ javascript novice.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend this one by Stafan Petre

http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

Comment: Thanks I tried that...but doesn't work. Especially when trying to use it in a <select> tag.

Comment: What is your expected behavior with select tag?

Comment: In  <select name="period" id="time"> I want the calendars to appear. I want one to be 'from date..' and the other 'to date....'

Comment: So you are planning to add a "custom interval" option to the select menu?

Comment: Yes....the user chooses the time frame and those two dates are sent back to server to filter the DB accordingly.

Comment: Check for onchange event of select menu, if the value is custom show the extra fields for start and end time.

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to html/javascript so unsure what that means.

Comment: Thanks that's cool,but how do the dropdown boxes pick out the abc select tags. I can't see it in the JS, for country?

Comment: Not clear. What do you mean? I just demonstrated how you can show a contextual interval picker if user opts for a custom interval.

Comment: My misunderstanding....I get it better now. So in <div id="interval_selector">
    Put two date selector inputs here using Stafan's plugin
</div> are there any particular selector inputs I need?

Comment: Check how Stefan did in his demo page, read source of that page. He has done with #dp4 and #dp5 two elements responsible for start and end date. You can mimic that. If you end up clueless comeback to SO with a new question cheers.